# Rails: Querying a specific table on a remote db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlanywhere

I am attempting to build a Rails app that queries a table on a remote db and displays selected information as HTML. The remote db is SQL Anywhere 16. The info lives on a particular table on the db, like: `db.inventory`. The column names are set up like: `primarykey | ItemName | ItemPrice | ItemQuantity | etc`. What I want to do is pull some of this information and display, for instance `<itemname /> <itemprice /> <itemquantity />`.

The remote db is SQL Anywhere 16, so I've installed the `sqlanywhere` gem and `activerecord-sqlanywher-adapter` in the gemfile.

I have the connection info set up in `database.yml` in addition to my local sqlite DBs:

```
my_external_database:
  adapter: sqlanywhere
  encoding: utf-8
  username: (username)
  password: (password)
  server: (name of the server)
  host: (ip of the server)
```

My model is set up like so:

```
class MyExternalModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection(:my_external_database)
    set_table_name 'tablename'
end
```

What I don't understand is (1) how to test the connection, and (2) how to query the particular table I need on the db. There are multiple tables on the database, but I only want to query a particular one. Thirdly, I'm not sure how I'll actually display this data, but... baby steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think `set_table_name` would let you specify the particular table.

You can also change the primary key...

```
self.primary_key = 'primaryKey'
self.table_name = 'db.inventory'
```

You can test the connection from a sanity perspective just by running `rails console` and then doing `MyExternalModel.first` or `MyExternalModel.find(1)`

You can use the model as is in your tests (test prepare will only clear down your test database) assuming you don't write to the remote database.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Steve! I've set up everything as you suggested, and have at least gotten a fancy new error:  

`LoadError: Could not load SQLAnywhere DBCAPI library`  

After doing some googling, it seems that this is some sort of problem with configuring SQLAnywhere, which I've installed locally and I think I configured. On my Windows computer I have no problem connecting to the database with e.g. Microsoft Access as long as I have the proper driver installed, I'm just not sure how that logic transfers to a Rails app built on my Mac...

Comment: Accepting this answer as the way to do it properly if you have everything else configured properly. Asked a second question about configuration [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604725/how-to-query-a-remote-sqlanywhere16-db-using-rails).